# recieve data as json and process at server side (java spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Send the parameters to server(spring framework) via  get request, i am thinking of making a json object of all those parameters and send in get request so that in java spring i can recieve at as a map at the controller class in spring , how to achieve this
I am new to spring please help me out

I so far tried to send those parameters singly like(pram1,param2,param3,param4)
and recieve at the server side as string by setting param to string in type script before making get request to the server->i recieved parameters as map in controller
but i dont think it is a best way

```
{
 param1: "param1"
 param2: "param2
 paramn: "paramn"
}
```

Send the above to server in the  controller  class ↓

```
@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestMap
```

I want to recieve parameters as

```
String param1=  requestMap.get("param1");
String param2=requestMap.get("param2");
```

If map type was an object it would be great so that i can recive any kind of object
 example
  at client side i am sending `{param1: "myName", id: 0001}`
  at server side `requestMap.get("param1"); requestMap.get("id");`

Comment: Read the Spring Getting Started guides. In particular, there's no need to manually extract parameters; define a DTO/`Request` class, and Spring will map it automatically.

Comment: If in future I would like to add some more parameters then I may have require to add fields in Dto as well , but I wouldn’t want to do that ...can i not map any kind of parameters to map without making use of dto class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you specify RequestParam as hashmap, it gets automatically converted from json by jackson. Alternatively, if you are using String as the param, you can use ObjectMapper to convert it to a Map and get values from there.

Comment: Wow I would want to try this one...I will comeback on this if I get the expected result. Thank you there

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by chrylis there's no need to manually extract parameters you can define a DTO/Request/POJO class, and Spring will map it automatically.

```
public class SampleDTO{
   private String param1;
   private String param2;
   .
   .
   //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution , yes this is one solution but I am not trying to make a dto just for the sake of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your incoming `json` to a `Hashmap` like so

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String yourMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {   

    String name = parameters.get("A"); //If your URL is http://test.com?A=ABC
    ...

}
```